# Decrypt scytale without knowing key

Tags: php, cryptography

So I've been asked to decrypt a text file encoded with the scytale algorithm. The problem is I don't know the key, so I have to iterate and try to guess which key gives a readable text. The idea is:

```
function decrypt($txt,$key){
    $out = "";
    for($i = 0; $i < $key; ++$i){
        for($j = $i; $j < strlen($txt); $j+=$key){
            $n = substr($txt,$j,1);
            $out.=$n;
            $j+=$key;
        }
    }
    return $out;
}

...

for($i = 1; $i <= 36567; ++$i){
                $decrypted = decrypt($in,$i);
}
```

Where 36567 is the length of the message and `$in` is the input text. Is there any way to do this without having to check each output? I've tried counting appearances of usual words without any luck. Is it really that complicated or I'm just simply going with a wrong approach? I don't even know if my code works as it is supposed to...

Comment: @ArtjomB. It is, but that's not the point. If you can help me with an algorithm in another language, I'll be happy to know

Answer (score 1):

This encryption is behaving like a [Vigenere cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher).  The Wikipedia page also documents cryptanalysis techniques.  These things are not hard to break, but it's hard to fully automate the attacks.  If you know some of the underlying plaintext, then computing the key is not too difficult.  Otherwise there are other approaches that involve looking at the difference between blocks or guessing the key length and doing frequency analysis on blocks.